# Android studio build fails

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I receive following warnings when I sync Gradle in Android Studio 4.1.2 from stable channel :

```
Failed to resolve: legacy-support-v4-1.0.0
Failed to resolve: asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0
Failed to resolve: media-1.0.0
Failed to resolve: swiperefreshlayout-1.0.0
Failed to resolve: slidingpanelayout-1.0.0
Failed to resolve: legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0
```

Here is my app module build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.android.storytel"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "String", "STORYTEL_BASE_URL", "\"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/\""
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Support libraries
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$version_support"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette-ktx:$version_palette"
    implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$version_espresso"

    // Android KTX
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$version_core"

    // Navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"

    // Architecture components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$version_lifecycle_extensions"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$version_retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$version_retrofit"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$version_retrofit"

    // Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$version_dagger"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$version_dagger"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$version_dagger"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$version_dagger"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$version_dagger"

    // Network
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$version_okhttp"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$version_picasso"
    implementation "com.github.florent37:picassopalette:$version_picasso_palette"

    // Moshi for parsing the JSON format
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$version_moshi"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$version_moshi"

    //Android RX
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$version_rxjava"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$version_rxandroid"

    // Timber
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$version_timber"

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$version_mockito"

    // Dependencies for Instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$version_junit_ext"

    // Espresso UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$version_espresso"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$version_espresso"

    // Testing Architecture components
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$version_lifecycle_test"

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$version_runner"
    androidTestImplementation  "androidx.test:rules:$version_rules"

    // AndroidX Test - JVM testing
    testImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$version_fragment"
}
```

When I build the project, I receive following error :

```
Could not resolve asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0.aar (androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0)
```

Here you can find my project : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Colors

Do you know why it happens and how to resolve it?

**Addenda** : I realized it is related to following dependency :

```
implementation "com.github.florent37:picassopalette:$version_picasso_palette"
```

Without this dependency, it works as expected.

Comment: I've downloaded your project and the IDE could download the dependencies you've mentioned above. You may try a VPN because if you use Iran IPs, you may get 403 or some other errors.

Comment: Thank you @Mohsen, I feel that I understand, So I am using a VPN, but it still does not download the dependencies.

Comment: There's no doubt about your understanding of this limitation and sanctions related stuff  but I guess the problem comes from your VPN. How about changing the location and using `File -> Invalidate caches - restart` after?

Comment: Thank you again, yes could be related to my VPN.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท, I realized that it is related to picassopalette. You can check it at the end of my question. Can you try once again? Can you build the project? I created an empty new application and add this dependency and I recieved the same warnings and error.

Comment: Just checked this library and seems like its using the [old support library](https://github.com/florent37/PicassoPalette/blob/master/picassopalette/build.gradle#L25) So, as "Rahat" said, you'll need to take care of this library (somehow, updating it or using another library instead) because you're using the AndroidX dependencies and implementations in your project. Also, please make sure you're using the latest wrapper : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip` in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`. (sometimes this is really helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with
`implementation "com.github.florent37:picassopalette:$version_picasso_palette"`
is that this library is that **it uses support library dependencies of android** and you are **trying to use it in a project where you are using jetpack library**.

You can resolve it by

1. **Using a version of that library which is migrated to JetPack.**.

OR

**You can download the zip of that library and extract it and then open it as a project and then from refactor menu migrate to `AndroidX` then you import that custom project as a library into your project.**

Comment: It seems there is no version of library migrated to JetPack, is available. So your later solution could be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You live in a country that is under sanctions. You must use a filter breaker.

you can use [this](https://shecan.ir/)

Comment: Thank you @Pouria, I feel that I understand, But I have already used a VPN, and I also tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. +1 for your VPN suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not resolve asynclayoutinflater-1.0.0.aar (androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0)
```

This means gradle cannot find that dependency anywhere. Make sure that the library can be accessed by gradle inorder to resolve the problem.

Basically gradle is seeing your dependency as some unresolvable gibberish.